# Retrieve shared text through share option list?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

How would i go about retrieving text that is shared through share option list that is in android?
This is my code that i am using. I am basicly sharing text to my app by selecting text from for example google, then right click on it and click share and i choose my app there. The share function is working great but i want to retrieve the actual text in my code that i am trying to share!

```
[Activity(Label = "TextRecieve", Icon = "@drawable/ic_home", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionSend }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "image/*", Label = "TextRecieve")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionSend }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "text/plain", Label = "TextRecieve")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionSendMultiple }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "image/*", Label = "TextRecieve")]


        Intent intent = Intent;
        String action = Intent.Action;
        String type = intent.Type;

        if (Intent.ActionSend.Equals(action) && type != null)
        {
            if ("text/plain".Equals(type))
            {
                // Handle text being sent
                // ...
                // ...
                // ...     

            }
            else if (type.StartsWith("image/"))
            {
                // Handle single image being sent
                // ...
                // ...
                // ...    
            }
        }
        else if (Intent.ActionSendMultiple.Equals(action) && type != null)
        {
            if (type.StartsWith("image/"))
            {
                // Handle multiple images being sent
                // ...
                // ...
                // ...                        
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen                    
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add this inside your "text/plain" statement. This will pull the text you are sharing to your app through the specified Intent "intent".

```
String sharedText = intent.GetStringExtra(Intent.ExtraText);
```

Total code would be

```
        Intent intent = Intent;
        String action = Intent.Action;
        String type = intent.Type;

        if (Intent.ActionSend.Equals(action) && type != null)
        {
            if ("text/plain".Equals(type))
            {
                // Handle text being sent
                // ...
                // ...
                // ...     
                String sharedText = intent.GetStringExtra(Intent.ExtraText);
            }
            else if (type.StartsWith("image/"))
            {
                // Handle single image being sent
                // ...
                // ...
                // ...    
            }
        }
        else if (Intent.ActionSendMultiple.Equals(action) && type != null)
        {
            if (type.StartsWith("image/"))
            {
                // Handle multiple images being sent
                // ...
                // ...
                // ...                        
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen                    
        }
```